# VB.net | how can i turn an access db record in to a tabcontrol add tabpage?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-access-2010

I have a question, I want to add a `TabPage` to my `TabControl` from an access record? I think it's something along these lines but it didn't work:

```
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\data\testing.Accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    con.Open()
    Dim constr As String = "SELECT ProductType, Discription FROM TblProductType"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(constr, con)
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "TblProductType")


    Me.TabControl1.TabPages.Add("Discription")

    con.Close()
```

Comment: a tabpage is an object, a UI Object.  Description is going to simply be a string.  you cant convert string to a TabPage, they are 2 very different things.  The Description can be the LABEL or TextBox .Text on a tab page though...and the "Discription" in the code is a literal, not something read from the database

Comment: You always have to define "it didn't work".  Looks like you want to add a new tab for every record in the table?  You need to iterate over the rows to do that.  But that will only get you an empty TabPage.

Comment: @larsTech Yes i want to add an tabpage for every record of the access db tab "Discription ", i'll fill the tabpage's later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over the row collection of the table:

```
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ProductType, Discription FROM TblProductType", con)
  Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While rdr.Read
      TabControl1.TabPages.Add(rdr("Discription").ToString)
    End While
  End Using
End Using
```

Of course, this only gives you an empty TabPage for every record and in it's current implementation, you don't have any reference to the record anymore.  That ProductType, if it's unique, should be used somewhere, too.